# Индексы блокируют базу

Tags: sql, postgresql

Нужно накатить индексы на базу. Но данных довольно много и они лочат её. Как быть? Пример индексов

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_registry_record_id ON payments.registry_record USING hash(id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_registry_record_registry_id ON payments.registry_record USING hash(registry_id);
```

Comment: Помолится, смирится с неизбежностью и накатить индексы с блокировкой.....
Есть конечно альтернатива, создать пустую таблицу, сделать индексы на ней, и перенести в нее все данные, правда опять проблема - во время переноса таблицы будут залочены но зато индексы будут накачены без блокировки xD

Comment: Вот что посоветовали  
CONCURRENTLY
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html

Comment: На критичных данных которые постоянно меняются? - такое себе.. если данные не часто меняются, то вообще нет проблемы через копию таблицы(с гарантиями целостности), а использовать на горячих таблицах отключение блокировок.... :) сисадмины делятся на три типа, те кто не делает бэкап, те кто уже делают бэкап, и тех кто уже проверяет сделанный бекап :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков "использовать на горячих таблицах отключение блокировок" вы критикуете тут какое решение? создание индексов с опцией CONCURRENTLY? Или что-то другое? Поясните

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Видимо что то другое, прочитал доку никакой проблемы подобной там не описано, но почему то на горячей таблице наши админы извращались с копированием... хотя и индексы были gist...